# GET the CURRENT LOCATION latitude and longitude

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

i have some code that i want to use to get the longitude and latitude...

here's the code

```
package ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;

import ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.Engine;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




/**
 * This is the main Activity that displays GUI.
 */
public class BroadcastChat extends Activity {
    // Debugging

    double LATITUDE = 37.42233;
    double LONGITUDE = -122.083;

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    private static final String TAG = "BcastChatUI";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    private Context _context;
    private TextToSpeech tts = null;
    private static int REQ_CODE = 1;
    private boolean ttsIsInit = false;
    private boolean awalan = false;
    private String pesan = "haha";
    private String tanya;

    private String siapa = "saya";
    private int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 1234; 


    // Layout Views
    private ListView mConversationView;
    private EditText mOutEditText;
    private ImageButton mSendButton;

    // Name of the connected device
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _context = this.getApplicationContext();

        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );




        // Set up the window layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(BroadcastChat.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(BroadcastChat.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(BroadcastChat.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(BroadcastChat.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    private void cektempat(){
         Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Anda ada di ");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                pesan = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                String message = pesan;
                sendMessage(message);
                startTextToSpeech2();
            }
            else{

                pesan = "Maaf saya tidak tahu anda dimana";
                String message = pesan;
                sendMessage(message);
                startTextToSpeech2();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            pesan = "IO EXCEPCTION ERROR";
            String message = pesan;
            sendMessage(message);
            startTextToSpeech2();
        }
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        awalan = false;
        setupChat();
        startTextToSpeech();
        String message = "Selamat datang di kiosban";

        sendMessage(message);
    }

    private void startTextToSpeech() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
    }

    private void startTextToSpeech2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
    }

    private void sendRecognizeIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Apa yang bisa kami bantu?");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            ttsIsInit = true;
                            if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH) >= 0)
                                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            tts.setPitch(0.8f);
                            tts.setSpeechRate(1.0f);


                            if (awalan == false){
                            awalan = true;
                            awalspeak();
                            }

                            if (awalan == true){
                                speak();
                                }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } 

            /**if no voice data is currently available,
             * start a new activity using the ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA action
             * from the TTS Engine class to initiate its installation
             */
            else {
                Intent installVoice = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installVoice);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if (matches.size() == 0)
                {
                    tts.speak("Heard nothing", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }




                tanya = matches.get(0);
                String pertanyaan = tanya;

                sendTanya(pertanyaan);










            }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "result NOT ok");
            }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }




    private void speak() {
        if (tts != null && ttsIsInit) {
            String text = pesan; 
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); 
        }
    }

    private void jawab() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanya", tanya));



/*            String valid = "1";*/      

        String response = null;


        try {   
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://kiosban.com/android/jamesband.php", postParameters);

        String res = response.toString();

        res = res.trim();

        res = res.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
        pesan = res;
        String message = pesan;

        if(res.equals("lokasi")){
            cektempat();    
        }else{
        sendMessage(message);
        startTextToSpeech2();
        }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    private void awalspeak() {
        if (tts != null && ttsIsInit) {
            String text = "selamat datang di kiosban";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }
    }
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
    }


    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
        mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
        mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
        mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);
        mOutEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mSendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "[sendButton clicked]");
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                sendRecognizeIntent();


            }
        });

        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }


    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }


    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }


    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }


    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0 ) {
            // We will send a message via wifi 

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please type a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        } 

        // Add message to UI

        mConversationArrayAdapter.add("James Band:  " + message);   


    }

private void sendTanya(String pertanyaan) {

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (pertanyaan.length() > 0 ) {
            // We will send a message via wifi 

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please type a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        } 


        mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + pertanyaan);
        jawab();
    }


    // The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
        new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL                 // return key 
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) // the key has been released
            {
                String pertanyaan = view.getText().toString();
                sendTanya(pertanyaan);


            }
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Its work when i using that code, it give the street name,
the script give me the street name from LATITUDE value and LONGITUDE value that i insert it manually,

but if i change the code below

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
```

on cektempat(); part to

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
```

i get my code doesnt work, i was set the permission to but the code still didnt work..

anybody can help me? thanks before

Here's the logcat

```
07-12 15:33:00.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:33:00.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:33:00.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:33:00.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:33:00.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:33:08.499: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13866): /system/csc/customer.xml ==> cannot open file
07-12 15:33:08.499: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13866): /system/csc/customer.xml can't open file
07-12 15:33:08.499: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13866): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
07-12 15:33:09.539: ERROR/power(411): *** set_screen_state 1
07-12 15:33:09.549: ERROR/SensorManager(411): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA220 delay= 60000 Listener= android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@407b0938
07-12 15:33:09.549: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): +__poll_activate: handle=0 enabled=1
07-12 15:33:09.549: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): > Accelerometer Write /sys/class/input/input3/enable 1
07-12 15:33:09.579: ERROR/SensorManager(411): reg :: handle = 0
07-12 15:33:09.629: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13638): + ON RESUME +
07-12 15:33:10.049: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:33:10.049: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:33:10.059: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:33:10.059: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:33:10.059: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:33:10.089: ERROR/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(411): onReceive() : intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x40000000 }
07-12 15:33:12.679: ERROR/InputDispatcher(411): channel '40547ff8 ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1/ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-12 15:33:12.679: ERROR/InputDispatcher(411): channel '40547ff8 ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1/ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-12 15:33:13.129: ERROR/Launcher(511): MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished. 
07-12 15:33:20.209: ERROR/su(13918): sudb - Opening database
07-12 15:33:20.669: ERROR/su(13918): sudb - Database opened
07-12 15:33:20.699: ERROR/su(13918): sudb - Database closed
07-12 15:33:34.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13967): /system/csc/customer.xml ==> cannot open file
07-12 15:33:34.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13967): /system/csc/customer.xml can't open file
07-12 15:33:34.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13967): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
07-12 15:33:37.419: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): +++ ON CREATE +++
07-12 15:33:37.609: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): ++ ON START ++
07-12 15:33:37.629: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): + ON RESUME +
07-12 15:33:37.649: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): - ON PAUSE -
07-12 15:33:37.879: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): + ON RESUME +
07-12 15:33:41.229: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): - ON PAUSE -
07-12 15:33:42.669: ERROR/UinboxLogger(14022): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> Context is android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@40524348
07-12 15:33:44.899: ERROR/BcastChatUI(13986): -- ON STOP --
07-12 15:33:50.679: ERROR/InputDispatcher(411): channel '408bc300 ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1/ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-12 15:33:50.679: ERROR/InputDispatcher(411): channel '408bc300 ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1/ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-12 15:34:00.069: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:34:00.069: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:34:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:34:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:34:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:34:16.109: ERROR/BcastChatUI(14164): +++ ON CREATE +++
07-12 15:34:16.249: ERROR/BcastChatUI(14164): ++ ON START ++
07-12 15:34:16.299: ERROR/BcastChatUI(14164): + ON RESUME +
07-12 15:34:16.339: ERROR/BcastChatUI(14164): - ON PAUSE -
07-12 15:34:17.129: ERROR/BcastChatUI(14164): + ON RESUME +
07-12 15:34:18.209: ERROR/GPSD(199): find_ril_request: not found.
07-12 15:34:18.399: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:34:19.579: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:34:20.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:34:20.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:34:20.099: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat.cektempat(BroadcastChat.java:147)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat.access$1(BroadcastChat.java:140)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at ncsu.course.android.broadcastchatui1.BroadcastChat$1.onEditorAction(BroadcastChat.java:442)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4721)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1290)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3855)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1130)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2627)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2030)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-12 15:34:26.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 15:34:26.409: ERROR/(411): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
07-12 15:34:55.339: ERROR/power(411): *** set_screen_state 0
07-12 15:34:55.339: ERROR/SensorManager(411): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@405198e0
07-12 15:34:55.349: ERROR/SensorManager(411): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@407b0938
07-12 15:34:55.349: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): +__poll_activate: handle=0 enabled=0
07-12 15:34:55.349: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): > Accelerometer Write /sys/class/input/input3/enable 0
07-12 15:35:00.069: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:35:00.069: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:35:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:35:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:35:00.079: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:35:20.939: ERROR/power(411): *** set_screen_state 1
07-12 15:35:20.949: ERROR/SensorManager(411): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA220 delay= 60000 Listener= android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@407b0938
07-12 15:35:20.949: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): +__poll_activate: handle=0 enabled=1
07-12 15:35:20.949: ERROR/SensorHAL(411): > Accelerometer Write /sys/class/input/input3/enable 1
07-12 15:35:20.949: ERROR/SensorManager(411): reg :: handle = 0
07-12 15:35:21.209: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): getOrientation portrait
07-12 15:35:21.209: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): drawDayText
07-12 15:35:21.209: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): width= 50
07-12 15:35:21.209: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): widthText= 62.0
07-12 15:35:21.209: ERROR/ClockWidget(10768): RIGHT
07-12 15:35:21.299: ERROR/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(411): onReceive() : intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x40000000 }
```

Comment: In Eclipse, go to window in title bar and then click on show view and after that select logcat.

Comment: Add this line LATITUDE=location.getLatitude(); and LONGITUDE=location.getLongitude(); in cektempat() function after Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your location is `null`. Note, that device can't get your location instantly.

Here is a lot of information about it
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

its look like location is null, then in your `try catch` block code you should add an `NullPointerException` to prevent app crash because location is `null`.

```
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

    if(addresses != null) {
        Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
        StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Anda ada di ");
        for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        }
        pesan = strReturnedAddress.toString();
        String message = pesan;
        sendMessage(message);
        startTextToSpeech2();

    } else{

        pesan = "Maaf saya tidak tahu anda dimana";
        String message = pesan;
        sendMessage(message);
        startTextToSpeech2();
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    pesan = "Maaf saya tidak tahu anda dimana";
    String message = pesan;
    sendMessage(message);
    startTextToSpeech2();
}
```

Check this link, maybe could help your case:
[the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)